# Non-square box in a Young tableau

Tags: ytableau, youngtab

I want to make a non-square box in a Young diagram, or for that matter, in a Young tableau. The purpose for this is to fit in more labels than one in a box, such that the dimensions of singly-labeled boxes change accordingly. For example, I want to have a Young tableau that visually presents as follows:

```
_____________

|1|1,2,3|3,5|
-------------
|2|4,5  |6| 
----------
|3|
```

I'm currently using ytableau package, but can be flexible with the package as long as it lets me implement this.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a good old array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 1,2,3 & 3,5\\
\hline
 2 & 4,5 & 6\\
\hline
 3&\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
\cline{1-1}
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]